# Understanding 'time' command output?

Tags: linux, time

There are several questions on this subject but none I've looked at provide quite what I need.

My output looks like this:

```
real    0m9.92s
user    0m0.12s
sys     0m0.02s
```

Based on content of a couple of other posts, I would think this is running a single thread, even though I have multiple CPU's available.  Is that a valid conclusion?

Second and more to my question, is the fact that "real" is almost 10 seconds, but neither of "user" or "sys", or their sum, come anywhere near 10 seconds.

Is the 9.92 - 0.12 - 0.02 "idle" time, waiting for some event to happen, or something else?

Comment: Yes, the 9.92 is the elapsed time between when your command started and when it finished. This could include time waiting (e.g., for I/O to complete) or simply when some other process was running (e.g., a process with a high enough priority to preempt yours and with enough threads to keep all the CPUs busy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell from that output whether the program in question is using multiple or a single thread.

Your assumption for “idle” time is valid.